# How do I politely communicate "your edit sucks" without getting into a war of edits?

Tags: discussion

I recently noticed that a question I asked was edited in an attempt to remove ambiguity, and I'm not a fan of the title at all (for one, it's redundant). If anyone has the power to edit, how do I avoid getting in a petty back-and-forth if I don't agree with the edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's your post, just roll the edit back.  If the edit is applied again, flag for moderator attention; edits wars are something that fundamentally require a moderator to resolve (typically by locking the post temporarily).

Comment: That's pretty much what I figured, but it's annoying that I even have to go there.

Comment: @moarboilerplate: Go where? To roll back the edit? Read the [help]. Everyone here can edit everyone's posts; it's part of the design of the site. It's senseless to get annoyed because the site is working as it is supposed to work. If it's not working the way you want, you can always post to Meta asking for it to change (although I'm absolutely certain that a request to stop allowing edits would be resoundingly and instantly declined).

Comment: Just make sure the new version really isn't an improvement. Self-vandalising is a serious offence.

Comment: @KenWhite it might prove useful to keep from engaging in dialogue with yourself so that I have a chance to address your statements as you make them. "Going there" refers to taking an action that is as much a shot over the bow as it is an effort to maintain the quality of a question/post. The fact that the only course of action available to me was one that may easily result in a conflict that, as stated by other posters, generally is only resolved by escalating to mods, was unsavory to me.

Comment: @moarboilerplate while I agree edit wars are annoying as feth.... how else would you want it to work? As Ken pointed out, edits are a big part of the site.... seems like there's no easy solution

Comment: @moarboilerplate: What *conversation with myself* are you so rudely referring to? I made a single comment addressed to you. There's no reason for your attitude or insults. If you don't want feedback or answers, simply don't post here. Otherwise, be polite. I wasn't rude to you or insulting in any way, and I'd appreciate the same in return.

Comment: @KenWhite fair point, I apologize for coming off so harshly. I got bent out of shape over the fact that I couldn't respond in time to say that even though I find it annoying that I can only roll back the edit and risk starting a war, I'm certainly not trying to start a cause for changing existing site behavior. I was simply asking the question to make sure I understood what my options are.

Comment: Which, as @Patrice points out and I agree, there is no easy solution.

Comment: @moarboilerplate: Apology accepted. :-) I could understand your being annoyed if you didn't have the ability to roll the edit back, but you've been given an opportunity to object by doing so. Moderators are here to resolve disputes, including disagreements over edits. What more would you like to see? Anything further would involve a feature request (for a change), which is the other alternative, and I provided that info. There was no offense intended, and if it came across that way I offer an apology as well.

Comment: @KenWhite well, this touches on the whole dynamic that surrounds the "come to me with solutions, not problems" concept. On one hand, I understand it's not constructive to be an armchair quarterback, but on the other hand I don't think it's necessarily wrong to call out something that seems less-than-ideal without having a solution for it. In this case I don't have one, but I do find it annoying that my only option is to do something that can touch off a conflict. Expressing my annoyance is not really me saying "hey, the site is broken," but "I feel this is a candidate for improvement."

Comment: @moarboilerplate: If it's a candidate for improvement, *suggest an improvement that could be made*. You're given a notification that the edit was made, the ability to reject it, and the ability to dispute when someone disagrees with your rejecting the edit. The only possibilities I see to give you more control would be a) stop allowing others to edit (no go), b) allow you to block a specific question from being edited (same thing), or c) the ability for you to refuse to allow your rejection of edits to be disputed (again, same thing). What's left? You want the ability to suspend the editor? :)

Comment: This is not wise advice. directed at an old alt account of mine, 5-6 teamed together and attacked me (they had previously attacked me, but in a different way), one (name withheld) edited something, I rolled back, he repeated, and so on... And when I kindly requested that they not change, guess what they attacked me! But I've never attempted the mod stuff. (Now that I'm brilliant and eternal, I'm enjoying the gangster life.)